# Get 10 highest ascending values of a column using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server and found my self in a predicament. I'd like to basically do an order on an order. The current SQL query I have is:

```
SELECT top 10 labelid 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY labelid DESC
```

This will return the top 10 values of the labelid column in descending order. I would like to however query the top 10 values, and have the results be in ascending order.

Is there an easy way of doing this without using procedures/plsql/etc?

Comment: "plsql" is the procedural SQL code language for **Oracle** - this won't work on SQL Server .... the SQL Server equivalent it **T-SQL** (or Transact-SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use your query as a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 labelid 
      FROM mytable 
      ORDER BY labelid DESC) A
ORDER BY labelid;
```

Comment: Very Interesting! I'll have to look into more derived table's as I'm decently new to SQL. Thank you!

Comment: Since you're new I'll note that you can't use `order by` in a derived table unless you use `top` as well. Not sure you'd actually try doing that... Many SQL purists will argue that `top` is really not a set-based approach. I think they would argue that using `row_number()` is better even though `top` may result in a faster query.

Answer (score 1):

Lamak's solution is great and derived tables are lots of fun but one very helpful way of organizing your code when using Sql Server and other platforms that have them is *Common Table Expressions [CTE]*  And while you are looking up/learning also check out Window Functions as they are helpful.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       labelid 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY labelid DESC) as RowNum
    FROM
       mytable 
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum <= 10
ORDER BY
    lableid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select * from (
  SELECT top 10 labelid FROM mytable ORDER BY labelid DESC) order by labelid
```